# Calculate CNF and DNF without truth tables

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

$$
\begin{array}{l}{\varphi_{1}=(\neg a \wedge b) \rightarrow \neg c} \\ {\varphi_{2}=((c \rightarrow \neg a) \wedge(\neg b \rightarrow \neg c)) \rightarrow(a \vee b \vee c)} \\ {\varphi_{3}=(a \vee \neg b) \leftrightarrow(a \wedge c)} \\ {\varphi_{4}=(\neg a \wedge c) \vee(a \rightarrow b)} \\ {\varphi_{5}=((a \wedge b) \vee(b \wedge \neg c)) \rightarrow(b \vee c)} \\ {\varphi_{6}=((a \uparrow b) \oplus(a \downarrow c))}\end{array}
$$

I have to calculate the cnf and dnf for all. I have problems doing that without the truth table. Have to do find the dnf for $4-6$ without truth table and cnf for $1-3$ without truth table. Can somebody help me doing that? Please.

Problems with $5$ my truth table tells me it's a tautology.

Calculating the DNF leads me to : $$
((\neg a \vee b) \wedge(c \vee \neg b)) \vee(b \vee c)
$$

Comment: Welcome to mathematics SE. People here like to see your work.  What have you tried? Please edit your post to include some of your thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: (Use [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence))

> $$p⊕q\equiv (p\land\neg q)\lor (\neg p\land q)\equiv(p\lor q)\land(\neg p\lor\neg q)\tag*{aka Xor}$$
>
> $$p ↓ q\equiv \neg p \land \neg q\tag*{aka Nor}$$
>
> $$p ↑ q\equiv \neg p\lor\neg q\tag*{aka Nand}$$

\begin{align}
\varphi_6&\equiv((a↑b)⊕(a↓c))\\
&\equiv(\neg a\lor\neg b)⊕(\neg a \land \neg c)\\
&\equiv((\neg a\lor\neg b)\lor(\neg a \land \neg c))\land(\neg(\neg a\lor\neg b)\lor\neg(\neg a \land \neg c))\\
&\equiv (((\neg b\lor\neg a)\lor \neg a)\land((\neg a\lor\neg b)\lor\neg c)\land(\neg(\neg a\lor\neg b)\lor\neg(\neg a \land \neg c))\\
&\equiv ((\neg b\lor(\neg a\lor \neg a))\land((\neg a\lor\neg b)\lor\neg c)\land(\neg(\neg a\lor\neg b)\lor\neg(\neg a \land \neg c))\\
&\equiv ((\neg b\lor \neg a)\land((\neg a\lor\neg b)\lor\neg c))\land(\neg(\neg a\lor\neg b)\lor\neg(\neg a \land \neg c))\\
&\equiv ((\neg a\lor \neg b)\land((\neg a\lor\neg b)\lor\neg c))\land(\neg(\neg a\lor\neg b)\lor\neg(\neg a \land \neg c))\\
&\equiv (\neg a\lor \neg b)\land(\neg(\neg a\lor\neg b)\lor\neg(\neg a \land \neg c))\\
&\equiv (\neg a\lor \neg b)\land((a\land b)\lor(a \lor c))\\
&\equiv ((\neg a\lor \neg b)\land (a\land b))\lor ((\neg a\lor \neg b)\land(a \lor c))\\
&\equiv (\neg( a\land b)\land (a\land b))\lor ((\neg a\lor \neg b)\land(a \lor c))\\
&\equiv \bot\lor ((\neg a\lor \neg b)\land(a \lor c))\\
&\equiv (\neg a\lor \neg b)\land(a \lor c)\tag*{CNF}\\
&\equiv (\neg a\land(a \lor c))\lor (\neg b\land(a \lor c))\\
&\equiv ((\neg a\land a) \lor (\neg a\land c)))\lor ((\neg b\land a) \lor (\neg b\land c)))\\
&\equiv (\bot \lor (\neg a\land c)))\lor ((\neg b\land a) \lor (\neg b\land c)))\\
&\equiv (\neg a\land c)\lor ((\neg b\land a) \lor (\neg b\land c)))\\
\end{align}

And since $(\neg a\land c)\lor (\neg b\land a)$ implies $(\neg b\land c)$ we can prove its DNF form is $(\neg a\land c)\lor (\neg b\land a)$.

---

Hints for $1-3$:
\begin{align}
\varphi_1&\equiv(\neg a\land b)\to c\\
&\equiv a\lor \neg b\lor c\tag*{CNF&DNF}\\
\varphi_2&\equiv\neg((\neg c\lor¬a)∧(b\lor¬c))\lor(a∨b∨c)\\
&\equiv(c\land a)\lor(\neg b\land c)\lor(a\lor b \lor c)\\
&\equiv a\lor b\lor c\tag*{CNF&DNF}\\
\varphi_3&\equiv (a∨¬b)↔(a∧c)\\
&\equiv (a∨¬b)\to(a∧c)\land(a\land c)\to(a\lor\neg b)\\
&\equiv ((\neg a\land b)\lor(a\land c))\land((\neg a\lor \neg c)\lor(a\lor \neg b))\\
&\equiv ((\neg a\land b)\lor(a\land c))\land\top\\
&\equiv (\neg a\land b)\lor(a\land c)\tag*{DNF}\\
&\equiv ((\neg a\land b)\lor a) \land ((\neg a\land b)\lor c)\\
&\equiv (\neg a\lor a)\land(a \lor b)\land(\neg a\lor c)\land(b\lor c)\\
&\equiv \top\land(a \lor b)\land(\neg a\lor c)\land(b\lor c)\\
&\equiv (a \lor b)\land(\neg a\lor c)\land(b\lor c)\\
\end{align}

And since $(a \lor b)\land(\neg a\lor c)\equiv(\neg a \to b)\land(a\to c)$ which will imply $(b\lor c)$, that will make it true in the statement, so we can prove its CNF is $(a \lor b)\land(\neg a\lor c)$.

(my suggestion is, for relatively detailed answers, ask one question a time.)

Comment: How did you get the tautology in line 3 for Number 3?

Comment: @rapiz notice there are both $\neg a \lor a$ in it, first apply Associative law to make ($\neg a \lor a$) together, then Negation law it become $\top$, that part will be $\top \lor (\neg c\lor \neg b)$, then by Domination law we have $\top$

Comment: Okey got it could you help me with 5 and 6 ? Have to finish it within 2 hours to pass a weekly test that leads to dropping or not and i don't quite get it i will try the dnf for 5 furhter ..

Comment: okay, i'll take a look

Comment: What i actually have $ (( \neg a \wedge \neg b ) \vee (\neg a \wedge \neg c) \vee (\neg b \wedge \neg b)) \vee (b \vee b)$

Comment: My truth table tells me it's a tautology

Comment: yep, $5$ is a tautology

Comment: By De Morgan's law $(\neg b\land \neg b)\equiv\neg(b\lor b)$, then by Negation law we have $\neg(b\lor b)\lor (b\lor b)\equiv\top$, then keep applying Domination law we can prove $\varphi_5\equiv\top$

Comment: Is my formula wrong? I guess i did something wrong i'm actually calculating again and get $ ((\neg a \wedge \neg b) \vee (\neg a \wedge c) \vee (\neg b \wedge \neg b) \vee (\neg b \vee c)) \vee (b \vee c)$

Comment: you mean $\varphi_5 ?$ your formula is a tautology which is equivalent to it

Comment: yeah, ok well than i will proceed to get to the tautology with this formula

Comment: @rapiz updated, as a proof for minimal DNF form, it's not yet finished, but that's the idea.

Comment: and $\varphi_4$ you can simplify it to $\neg a\lor b$, as it's DNF&CNF form

Comment: Since with Identity law $(\neg a\lor b)\land((\neg a\lor b)\lor c)\equiv((\neg a\lor b)\lor\bot)\land((\neg a\lor b)\lor c)$, by distributive law that $(\neg a\lor b)\lor (\bot\land c)$, apply domination law we have $\neg a\lor b$

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can proceed (I hope that this exercise intends to teach you that **using the truth tables is a better method**):

1. Convert all operators so that only the operators $\neg,\, \vee, \, \wedge$ remain(eg $\phi \to \psi$ becomes $\neg \phi \vee \psi$).
2. Use either distributivity  until you're in conjonctive (resp. disjunctive) form. Favor distributivity of $\vee$ over $\wedge$ if you want CNF and vice-versa. 
   Don't forget to simplify using associativity and idempotency after each step.

As an example, let's compute the CNF of $\varphi_4$ :
$$\begin{eqnarray} \varphi_4  & = &(\neg A \wedge C)\vee (A \to B)\\   &\equiv &  (\neg A \wedge C)\vee (\neg A \vee B)\\ &\equiv& \big(\neg A \vee (\neg A \vee B)\big)\wedge \big( C\vee (\neg A \vee B) \big) \\ &\equiv& (\neg A \vee B)\wedge ( C\vee \neg A \vee B)\end{eqnarray}$$

$(\neg A \vee B)\wedge ( C\vee \neg A \vee B)$ is in conjonctive form, it is hence the CNF of $\varphi_4$.

Comment: @rapiz Can you edit your original post and show us how you get the DNF of $\varphi_4$?

Comment: Done it correct?

Comment: @rapiz No, the last equality doesn't hold. I suggest that you start with CNF and use distributivity of $\wedge$ over $\vee$.

Comment: Don't get it. Yeah i negated the second term my bad. Want to understand rewrite these equations. What do you mean?

Comment: is this calculation right?

Comment: No. Introducing double negations will leed you to nowhere, since they will eventually undo each other. Just try to apply distributivity of $\wedge$ over $\vee$ in the CNF.

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how with 4 literals

Comment: Set $\psi := (C \vee \neg A \vee B)$ and use distributivity in $(\neg A \vee B)\wedge \psi$.

Comment: How did you get that psi??

Comment: In my case i would set $(\neg a \wedge c)$ as $\psi$

Comment: $\psi := (\neg a \wedge c)$ So $\psi \vee (\neg a \vee b)$ Now i get $(\psi \vee \neg a) \wedge ( \psi \vee b)$